# BFS in large space taking too much time

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7

I am using a modified BFS algorithm in python2 with following class as Node of tree:

```
class Node(object):
def __init__(self, data, parent):
    self.data = data
    self.children = []
    self.parent = parent


def add_child(self, obj):
    self.children.append(obj)
```

My BFS algorithm should be able to traverse a node **more than once** based on certain conditions. Due to this fact, the memory consumption and time taken to run are going pretty high( 5 minute is the limit). For search space of 64, it goes on for about 30 seconds(with about 4-5gb memory usage) and for search space of 100, it goes beyond 5 minute limit with memory usage >10gb. Is there anything I can do to fix that?

```
def bfs_search(start):
    n = Node(start, None)
    queue = Queue.Queue()
    queue.put(n)
    flag2 = 0
    while queue is not empty:
        next = queue.get()
        for node in graph[next.data]:
            #CHECK CONDITION
            if condition is true:
                element = Node(node, next)
                #CHECK ENDING CONDITION
                if ending condition is true:
                    return True
                next.add_child(element)
                queue.put(element)
    return False
```

As you can see I am not using anything to store visited nodes as I need to visit nodes more than once.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you getting `current` ? Also you are appending to `current` why?

Comment: @nevets1219 Sorry about that. Fixed the code.

Comment: Also what is the meaning of `dat` and `par`? I'm assuming `dat` is data - you have both `dat` and `data`. Also why are you doing a lookup in graph, what's that suppose to accomplish? There's no real point appending anything to `next`, please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry dat is data and par is parent. I am looking up the graph because  I only need the child to be traversed if its connected to not only its parent but also its grandparent, great grandparent... all the way upto start node. Also graph is actually the graph that needs to be traversed in form of a dictionary(defaultdict).

Comment: Is it intentional to use `next.data` in `graph[next.data]`? How is `graph` created? Why don't you use the nodes children when traversing the graph? Are you sure that you don't have cycles (the memory usage for so few nodes makes me think? When you say search space, do you mean total number of nodes or number of levels your BFS searches?